# Retrieve free space into my main partition on my new cloned installation

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I used clonezilla to clone my current ubuntu installation on a new SSD drive.

It worked fine, but i noticed my free space is still the same (The old SSD was a 120gb one and the new one is a 240Gb)

on the KDE partition manager i noticed i have unallocated space, and i would like to be able to retrieve that unallocated space on my current work partition.

How can i do this? i have an idea but i would like to ask before i do any changes on this.

Thank you in advance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOGJG.png)

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a **swapoff** on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a **swapon** on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- start `gparted`
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sda2 all the way to the right
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sda5 all the way to the right
- click the Apply icon